# Use half bridge driver with one mosfet

Tags: mosfet

I need a single mosfet driver but only have half bridge drivers (IRF2004) in my parts box.

Is there a risk I destroy them if I only connect one mosfet to them? Any other risks which I should be aware of?

Comment: I guess, no problem. Use the lower side gate driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done quite often, especially on bigger ICs incorporating several half bridge drivers. Unused half bridge drivers can be used to drive single MOSFETs.